# Label For Control Group (not individual control) - 508 Compliance HTML

Tags: html, section508

Suppose I have the following form and I need to make it 508-Compliant by including a `Label For=<id>` for every control descriptor.

In the case of simple text boxes, it's clear that the `Label For=<id>` will point to the ID of the text boxes.

In the case of Choice controls, such as radiobuttons/checkboxes, the `Label For=<id>` will point to the ID of **individual choices**.

But what should be done with the descriptor of a control group, i.e. **Speed Assessment** in the following example?

```css
input[type=radio] {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

<label for="distance">Distance:</label>
<input type="text" id="distance"/>

<label for="unit">Unit:</label>
<select id="unit">
   <option value="miles">Miles</option>
   <option value="km">Km</option>
</select>

<p>Speed Assessment:</p>

<label for="speedSlow">Slow</label>
<input type="radio" name="speed" id="speedSlow"/><br/>
<label for="speedMedium">Medium</label>
<input type="radio" name="speed" id="speedMedium"/><br/>
<label for="speedFast">Fast</label>
<input type="radio" name="speed" id="speedFast"/><br/>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<p>Speed Assessment:</p>`

Is a header, in my opinion and should be `<h1>Speed Assessment:</h1>`

it would not be h1 depending on the use of previous headers.